# How can I fix this error 'Unknown module type'?

Tags: verilog

My top model:

```
 module top (G1, Y1, R1, G2, Y2, R2, BT1, BT2, clk, rst);
 input BT1, BT2, clk, rst;
 output G1, Y1, R1, G2, Y2, R2;
 wire En1, En2, En3, CNT_RES, FF_RES, TC_30, TC_5, GE_15, B1, B2, request;

 Controll_Unit c1(G1, Y1, R1, G2, Y2, R2, CNT_RES, FF_RES, B1, B2, BT1, BT2, clk, rst, En1, En2, En3);

 Counter t1(TC_30, TC_5, GE_15, CNT_RES, FF_RES, rst, clk);

 dff_sr q1(GE_15, clk, request);

 assign En1=TC_30||GE_15&&B1;
 assign En2=TC_30||GE_15&&B2;
 assign En3=TC_5;
 assign request = BT1||BT2;
endmodule
```

My dff model:

```
module dff_sr(output GE_15 ,input clk, request);
reg  GE_15;

always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    if(request)
     GE_15<=1;
  end
   endmodule
```

Why does my `dff_sr` code have this unknown error?  I want this problem quickly solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up ANSI and non-ANSI module port declarations.  Change:

```
module dff_sr(output GE_15 ,input clk, request);
    reg  GE_15;
```

to:

```
module dff_sr(output reg GE_15 ,input clk, request);
```

This uses ANSI style.  I don't get the same error as you do, but I do get this compile warning on Cadence:

```
reg  GE_15;
         | xmvlog: *W,ILLPDX : Multiple declarations for a port not allowed
           in module with ANSI list of port declarations (port 'GE_15') [12.3.4(IEEE-2001)].
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 23.2.2 *Port declarations*.